# Slack won't let me install new GitHub app saying I'm over free app quota, BUT I AM NOT?

Tags: slack

Slack has been nagging me ceaselessly to upgrade the GitHub application, so I decided to go ahead and do it. I went to slack.github.com and clicked the "Add to Slack" button, and it redirected me to a page that said I was over the 10 apps quota for a free plan. So I went to app management and **uninstalled** the old GitHub app following [the relevant steps here](https://slack.com/intl/en-pl/help/articles/360003125231-Remove-apps-and-custom-integrations-from-your-workspace), and now the old legacy GitHub integration is **no longer listed** in the installed apps listing, and the listing has **only 9 entries**.

However, when I retry installing the new GitHub application by clicking the "Add to Slack" button on the slack.github.com page, I get the same result as previously: a message that says my workspace can't add more apps because I am hitting the 10 apps quota. **But I am not hitting that quota! I only have 9 apps in the listing now, and should be able to install 10th!** What gives?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used 'workflow steps' in the past (only possible with a premium plan), they also count towards your quota. So it is possible that when you include workflow steps, the number of apps would cross the free app limit.

To confirm this, you can check your published [workflows](https://app.slack.com/workflow-builder/) here.

If that doesn't solve the problem, try [contacting](https://www.slack.com/help/requests/new) Slack. They are a helpful bunch of people.